# How to get list of folders and subfolders from full path in  SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server-2008, directory

I have a column in my SQL Server table with file paths (with folders and subfolders)

For example:

```
/Hidden Reporting/Validation Report
/Top Reporting/Inner/TopTools Report
```

I currently have a query which returns all main folders of these path:

```
Select Distinct 
    LEFT((substring(Path, 2, (LEN(Path) - 1))), CHARINDEX('/', (substring(Path, 2,(LEN(Path) - 1)))) - 1) AS Folder
FROM dbo.Catalogs
Where Type=2
```

Result:

```
Hidden Reporting
Top Reporting
```

But I need to get subfolders too.

For example:

```
Hidden Reporting
Top Reporting
Inner
```

How can I do it in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a table valued function to split the string. I got the below function to split from some where else

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @sString varchar(5000),
    @cDelimiter char(1)
)
RETURNS @tParts TABLE ( part varchar(5000) )
AS
BEGIN
    if @sString is null return
    declare     @iStart int,
                @iPos int
    if substring( @sString, 1, 1 ) = @cDelimiter 
    begin
        set     @iStart = 2
        insert into @tParts
        values( null )
    end
    else 
        set     @iStart = 1
    while 1=1
    begin
        set     @iPos = charindex( @cDelimiter, @sString, @iStart )
        if @iPos = 0
                set     @iPos = len( @sString )+1
        if @iPos - @iStart > 0                  
                insert into @tParts
                values  ( substring( @sString, @iStart, @iPos-@iStart ))
        else
                insert into @tParts
                values( null )
        set     @iStart = @iPos+1
        if @iStart > len( @sString ) 
                break
    end
    RETURN

END
```

Now you can execute the select query below to get the desired output

```
SELECT part
FROM Catalogs C 
cross APPLY dbo.SplitString( substring([Path],1,LEN([Path]) - 
 CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE([Path]))) ,'/') AS Results
WHERE ISNULL(part,'') <> ''
```

Comment: Thats working realy good, but in this case we have one list with all folders, subfolders and FILE NAMES. The last part of this path is file name (Validation Report,TopTools Report) / So the structure of path is: /Folder1/Folder2/FileName  But we need only Folders and SubFolders.